# How to structure Dependency Injection in C#

Tags: c#

So I've implemented what I believe is called dependency injection (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

I've got a FooModel class that maintains the state of Foo. There's some async methods in here that try some stuff. Usually they work, sometimes they fail at various stages. I would like the implementation of FooModel and UpdateFoo() to force callers to implement their handling of what happens in UpdateFoo(). Here's a simple example:

```
public class FooModel
{
    private FooState fooState;

    public async Task UpdateFooAsync(IHandler handler)
    {
        try
        {
            var newFooState = await Something();
            fooState = newFooState;

            handler.ItWorked();
        }
        catch
        {
            handler.ItDidntWork();
        }
    }
}

public interface IHandler
{
    public void ItWorked();
    public void ItDidntWork();
}
```

Now, there are multiple other models that might need to call UpdateFoo(). For example, consider the BarModel:

```
public class BarModel
{
    private BarState barState;
    private FooModel foo;

    public Bar()
    {
        this.foo = ModelProvider.Foo;
    }

    public void DoBar()
    {
        foo.UpdateFoo(new Handler(this));
    }

    private void Continue() {}
    private void TryOtherThing() {}

    public class Handler : IHandler
    {
        private BarModel bar;

        public Handler(BarModel bar)
        {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public void ItWorked()
        {
            bar.Continue();
        }
        public void ItDidntWork()
        {
            bar.TryOtherThing();
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a simple example. There may be 2 - 6 "forks" in UpdateFoo(). And there may be several different classes that need to call UpdateFoo(). I want to force all these calling classes to do something on each of these different "forks", which is why I used the interface.

However, it seems incredibly cumbersome to have to explicitly implement a nested class for every class that wants to call UpdateFoo(). Especially since I have to pass the parent class as an argument to the constructor, etc. The idea of a nested class in general doesn't really sit right with me.

Is what I've done a good idea? Or is it horrible? Are there cleaner refactorings? I can't really tell.

Edit:
Changed some things as per Kai Brummund's recommendations

Comment: What you are doing looks more like the Command- or Strategy-Pattern to me. I'd recommend you look up these two. Dependency Injection is more about the dependencies of a class at construction/initialization time. Callers of methods should not be aware of the internal dependencies of your class.

Comment: Other OT hints: Async methods should reflect that in their name: UpdateFooAsync() and you should never use async void if possible. Make it async Task.

Comment: There's also a point where your code explicitly breaks dependency injection: Your BarModel has a dependency on Foo, but you are getting it via a ModelProvider in the constructor. If you would allow to pass in the modelprovider, or even the Foo itself as arguments, that would be dependency injection. 

Comment: So many strategies to read up on, it's difficult to see the subtle differences between them all. :) But thank you, highlighting the construction/initialization thing makes it a lot clearer. I was also referring to the way the Handler object is passed to UpdateFooAsync(). I suppose because it's only a method it's not really considered a part of a design pattern?

Comment: Most design patterns are defined very open (and that's for good). Dependency Injection especially is a very broad pattern with lots of ways of doing it (good, bad and easy ways).

If you come from a Java background: AsyncTask in Java works in a very similar way. You pass in an object with "before, do and after" methods.

What you are doing here is pretty high level: Do you really need that many handler cases? Can't you just throw an exception or return an error code? The handler interface adds a lot of complexity, as users of your API always have to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use delegates instead of implementing an interface. As long as there are only two methods, this should be ok:

```
public async void UpdateFoo(Action successAction, Action failureAction)
{
    if (successAction == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("successAction");
    }
    if (failureAction == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("failureAction");
    }

    try
    {
        var newFooState = await Something();
        fooState = newFooState;

        successAction();
    }
    catch
    {
        failureAction();
    }
}
```

And use it like this...

```
public void DoBar()
{
    foo.UpdateFoo(Continue, TryOtherThing);
}
```

... or this:

```
public void DoBar()
{
    foo.UpdateFoo(() => Console.WriteLine("Epic win!"), () => Console.WriteLine("Fail."));
}
```

Comment: There are often more than 2, sometimes up to 8 or so. That's probably a bit too much, what do you think?

Comment: Are they all mandatory? You could create a class that holds all delegates and put that as argument, or create a fluent interface if you want it fancy.